# Flexbox, one exception on equal height of coumns in rows

Tags: css, flexbox

I am using flexbox to create a very simple grid. In every row, each element has the same height as the other elements in the row. I would like to make an exception for one element only, because I'd like to use this element as a dropdown to show more information.

I made a very simple sample here:
https://jsbin.com/fadizozija/edit?html,css,output

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4 <br/> prev / next column should expand in height</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
    <div class="expand">7<br /> this column <br /> should <strong>not</strong> expand <br />the prev / next column</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
}
div.wrapper div {
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
  background: lightgrey;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
/* div.wrapper  div.expand {
 position:absolute;
  background: white;
  width: calc(50% - 28px)
} */
```

Column **4** should have the same height as the elements in the same row, so this is working fine. However, for column **7** I would like it to not do that. It should keep the current position, but it should not expand the height of 8. Instead it should "float" above 9 and 8 should keep it's current height.

Position absolute does what I want, but it makes the column leave the grid and position in front. I commented it out in CSS.

Anyone has any suggestions? I can solve it using floats and some height equalizer, but that seems like the worst solution.

Comment: Flexbox is **designed** to have equal height items in it's rows. Unfortunately, flexbox is not your option here.

Comment: Thanks Paulie_D, that's probably why I couldn't solve it. :)

Comment: margin-bottom: auto; to the eight element will fix it

Comment: Thank you Temani, this works but pushes the next row down as with align-self: baseline

Answer (score 0):

**Use CSS align-self Property**

Use align-self utilities on flexbox items to individually change their alignment on the cross axis (the y-axis to start, x-axis if flex-direction: column ).

**flex-start**:-

`flex-start:` cross-start margin edge of the item is placed on the cross-start line

```
div.wrapper div:nth-child(8){align-self: flex-start;}
```

**OR**

**baseline:**

`baseline:` items are aligned such as their baseline are aligned

```
div.wrapper div:nth-child(8){align-self: baseline;}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, but the next row is still pushed down. As with margin-bottom: auto;

Comment: Can you Please send me screenshot link? what is happening with next row? It is working fine here.

Comment: I think we have the same result https://ibb.co/jyx35mM but I would like 7 to act as a dropdown. So if it's open it falls over 9. Now the whole row expands.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding an extra div column 7. This div is positioned absolute, while 7 is positioned relative. With left 0 and z-index 1 i can position the extra div ontop of 7, so it looks like an expanded column.

**Result:**
https://jsbin.com/pozuhadatu/edit?html,css,output

**HTML**

```
<div>7<br /><div class="expand">this column <br /> should <strong>not</strong> expand <br />the prev / next column</div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.wrapper div.expand {
  position:absolute;
  left: -10px;
  width: calc(100%);
  z-index: 1;  
}
```